# Access vertices of a line in Python

Tags: line, shapely, linestring, vertices

Given a `shapely.geometry.linestring`: How do you access single vertices using Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Shapely User Manual](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#linestrings):

> The defining coordinate values are accessed via the coords property.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1)])
for coord in line.coords:
    print(coord)

(0.0, 0.0)
(1.0, 1.0)
```